# DENSE_RANK on Calculated Column

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

```
CASE 
          WHEN [col1] = 's' THEN 8
          WHEN [col1] = 't' THEN 6 
          WHEN [col1] = 'u' THEN 9
          WHEN [col2] = 'v' THEN 1
.......
END AS product,
DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY product ASC) AS [Rank]
FROM dbo.TableA
```

`DENSE_RANK()` is not working on calculated column `Product`, showing

> Invalid column name 'product'.

How to apply `DENSE_RANK()` on product?

Comment: Just to be clear: this has nothing to do with `DENSE_RANK()` - you just cannot refer to a newly introduced column alias later on in your `SELECT` statement - you have to use an approach as Mithrandir shows in his response

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
SELECT 
  *, 
  DENSE_RANK() over (order by product)
FROM (
SELECT 
  CASE 
          WHEN [col1] = 's' THEN 8
          WHEN [col1] = 't' THEN 6 
          WHEN [col1] = 'u' THEN 9
          WHEN [col2] = 'v' THEN 1
 ...
END AS product
FROM dbo.TableA
) t
```